# Scrapping company data through linkedin api

Tags: web-scraping

I'm trying to figure out the ways to extract our company's posts,comments to do sentiment analysis based on keyword. There are scrappers available , i'm not sure whether the linkedin allows it. Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a google sheet,there are some steps,

1. First paste the google sheet's url
2. Either get the [Linkedin session cookie manually](https://texau.app/help)
   or [use our chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/texau-chrome-extension/chilggcmkfgpjeljoebelchjjafdedao) to do it with the click of a button. You can also create
   variables to avoid entering Linkedin session cookies again & again. Here
   is a guide to [creating variables on TexAu](https://texau.app/help).
3. Input the column containing the post URLs. Make sure you choose the right
   one for successful execution.
4. If you have purchased a proxy (you will have to add a proxy to your
   account) make sure you toggle the option. Furthermore, if you are executing
   on a desktop, you don’t have to worry about the proxy.

For the final touch, make sure you have set the sheet as public so the TexAu can access it

more methods are there in this [link](https://texau.app/automation/extract-commenters-from-linkedin-posts) you  chose any one them.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Just wanted to ask doing these would be legal? Because i saw linkedin terms and agreements that linkedin does not supports third party service.

Comment: you can ask that to chat if you have doubts many will do this, once confirm me that these steps are working fine after clearing your doubts